# Dynamic adding unknown in advance properties to the object with getters/setters

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to add new properties to the object, getting the names for them from the properties of another object. And I need to define setters/getters for new properties:

```
var params = {
  id: 123,
  name: 'Old master'
};

var Master = new function() {
  var values = {};

  for(var key in params) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
      enumerable: true,
      set: function(value) {
        values[key] = value;
      },
      get: function() {
        return values[key];
      }
    });
  }

  return this;
}()

Master.id = 234;
Master.name = 'New master';
console.log(Master.id); // returns 'New master' but I need '234'
```

How can I define setters/getters to make them setting/getting the rigth property? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in 'var key'. So I added 'use strict'; line and changed 'var key' to 'let key':

```
'use strict'; 

var params = {
  id: 123,
  name: 'Old master'
};

var Master = new function() {
  var values = {};

  for(let key in params) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
      enumerable: true,
      set: function(value) {
        values[key] = value;
      },
      get: function() {
        return values[key];
      }
    });
  }

  return this;
}()

Master.id = 234;
Master.name = 'New master';
console.log(Master.id); // now it returns '234'
```